# does calling locationmanager.removeupdates permanently removes it in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, location, locationmanager

I'm creating an App to send Latitude and Longitude via SMS if the mobile moves in one minute interval.
I used an `ArrayList` to save six `LatLngs` after ArrayList reaches six elements it sends SMS. If the device stops moving within the time of six minutes then the `ArrayList` will be less than six. If the device not moves for twenty minutes then it sends the unfilled ArrayList. I used `CountdownTimer` to achieve this.
It worked fine it sends `LatLngs` as long as I move. But, if I stop before the ArrayList fills it sends the ArrayList whatever it has after 20 minutes. Not a problem with that. But, after that it keeps sending SMS in one minute interval. My Code is

```
private void sendLog() {

    Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Sending Log",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final SharedPreferences account=getSharedPreferences("admins", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String interval=account.getString("lti", "");
    int timeInterval=Integer.parseInt(interval);

    final LocationManager logManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    logManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, timeInterval * 60000, 100, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM,yy");
            String time = sdf.format(date);
            final String dateLog = sdf1.format(date);

            loglist.add("!+" + dFormat.format(latitude) + ",+" + dFormat.format(longitude) + "," + time);
            Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, loglist.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1200000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    if (loglist.size() == 6) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < loglist.size(); j++) {
                            log.append(loglist.get(j).toString());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, log.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1", ""), null, "  " + log.toString() + "!" + dateLog + "!", null, null);
                        loglist.removeAll(loglist);
                        log.setLength(0);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (loglist.size()<6) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < loglist.size(); j++) {
                            log.append(loglist.get(j).toString());
                        }
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1", ""), null, "  " + log.toString() + "!" + dateLog + "!", null, null);
                        loglist.removeAll(loglist);
                        log.setLength(0);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

I think of calling `logManaager.removeupdates()`. Does this cause the `locationUpdates` cannot be called again. Because I want the device send whenever it moves. Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition of calling `logManager.removeUpdates()` is correct.

Once calling `removeUpdates()` you can request updates once again.